# Stop Xcode from crashing when copy and pasting a SpriteNode in an .sks file?

Tags: xcode, skspritenode

I have lots of SpriteNodes in an .sks file. I want to copy and paste them but every time I do, Xcode crashes. Is this a bug or is there a way to fix this?

Comment: If Xcode crashes out from under you, it's a bug. Report it.

Comment: Okay, will do. Thanks